# How can I add conditions to a WHERE clause based on a variable and make it perform well?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a monstrous query with many JOINs that performs well until I add the many many WHERE conditions it has. What I wanted was to preserve it as close as possible to it's original form, so no string interpolation is used to determine what the conditions that must apply in the WHERE clause are. Here's a toy version of the query:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Email
FROM People P
-- if a then b == !a || b == AND (NOT(a) OR (b))
WHERE (NOT (@inputParam = 0) OR (P.FirstName = 'John'))
  AND (NOT (@inputParam = 1) OR
       (P.LastName = 'Smith'))
  AND (NOT (@inputParam > 2) OR
       (P.Age > 28))
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf1041/1).

The trick I have used is this equivalence: `if a then b == !a || b == AND (NOT(a) OR (b))`, in other words, apply this condition if the parameter has this value.

This surprisingly works, but it performs miserably once is tested against many records. It seems SQL Server doesn't apply the short-circuit evaluation style we can find in C#, for example.

So here's the question. How can I achieve the same effect I'm looking for and still have good performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a `RECOMPILE` in your `OPTION` clause? Otherwise you could very likely to be suffering from an inappropriately cached plan.

Comment: i usually just bite the bullet and convert such code to dynamic sql

Comment: I'd suggest several *unioned* queries instead of using *or*, that way SQL Server can optimally use indexes for each column.

Comment: Suggested reading: Erland Sommarskog's Dynamic Search Conditions https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Also see [the kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Age, Email
FROM People P
WHERE 
(CASE 
     WHEN @inputParam = 0 THEN (CASE WHEN P.FirstName = 'John' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     ELSE 1 
END) = 1
AND 
(CASE 
     WHEN @inputParam = 1 THEN (CASE WHEN P.LastName = 'Smith' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     ELSE 1 
END) = 1
AND 
(CASE 
     WHEN @inputParam > 2 THEN (CASE WHEN P.Age > 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     ELSE 1 
END) = 1;
```